Docker compose doesn't set env variable through environment in compose.yaml
This is my compose.yaml, and i don't have any .env in my working dir.
services:
  service_a:
    image: "my_img"
    environment:
      - WORKER_NUMBER=1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: >
      bash -c "export PATH=/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
      && conda init
      && echo "WORKER_NUMBER=${WORKER_NUMBER}"
      && tail -f /dev/null"

When i use docker compose up i get a warning:
WARN[0000] The "WORKER_NUMBER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 

And the print result is
WORKER_NUMBER=

Why and how to set env var by environment attribute correctly? Thanks for any helps!
My Docker & Docker compose ver:
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.15


Docker Compose version v2.27.0


UPDATE:
Fix the copy-paste error of echo cmd.

There's an unbalanced " in your command string after echo. If I try to replicate your issue using the debian image and replacing your commands with a simple env, then WORKER_NUMBER is set, so it works as expected for me.

@HansKilian Sorry, it's a copy-paste error. Actually the cmd is closed and it doesn't work.

Also see this answer similarly describing the need to double the $, though with apparently a very different symptom.

"environment:" adds the variables to the container, but referencing the variable as ${var} in the compose file gets compose to resolve it from the docker compose cli environment.
Rewrite the command as an array like this and escape the variables like this so they are resolved in the container:
services:
  service_a:
    image: "my_img"
    environment:
      - WORKER_NUMBER=1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - |
     export PATH=/root/miniconda3/bin:$$PATH
     conda init
     echo "WORKER_NUMBER=$$WORKER_NUMBER"
     tail -f /dev/null

alternatively, to supply WORKER from the outside:
WORKER=2 docker compose up
with the following changes will resolve "WORKER" as the compose file is being parsed. As shown, you can supply defaults.
services:
  service_a:
    environment:
      - WORKER_NUMBER=${WORKER-0}
    command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - |
     echo "WORKER_NUMBER=$$WORKER_NUMBER"
     echo "WORKER=${WORKER}"

Reference:
Interpolation (Compose Specification)

Thank you for your answer. I have something to do now so I can't try it. I will try your solution later. Thanks again!

Hello, I tried my best but couldn't find the escape method of double dollar sign. Where did you know this method? Can you provide a manual or document? Thank you!

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/12-interpolation/
